# struts 2 radio button display issue

Tags: java, struts2

I want to display data under columns cID, cName and cStatus with the first column displaying a radio button. cList is a list of Value Objects(VO=(cID,cName,cStatus)).
If i select a radio button in front of a record(cID,cName,cStatus) then cIdDetails should be set as the value of cID. 
By the following code, the value of cIdDetails is set correctly.

```
        <s:iterator value="cList">
            <tr>
                <td width="1%"><s:radio theme="simple" name="cIdDetails"
                    list="cID" label="&nbsp;"
                    onclick="details()" /></td>
                <td width="20%"><s:property value="cID" /></td>
                <td width="59%"><s:property value="cName" /></td>
                <td width="20%"><s:property value="cStatus" /></td>
            </tr>
        </s:iterator>
```

The only problem is that i dont want to show any label for the radio button. 
Above code sets the label as cID and displays it as label of radio button.

Required Output

```
                cId          cName          cStatus
 radiobtn1      ID1           ABC           Single
 radiobtn2      ID2           XYZ           Married
```

Observed Output

```
                   cId          cName          cStatus
 radibtn1 ID1      ID1           ABC           Single
 radibtn2 ID2      ID2           XYZ           Married
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a map

```
<s:radio theme="simple" name="cIdDetails" list="#{cID:''}" onclick="details()"/>
```

[Look here](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/how-do-i-render-a-single-radio-button.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use the listValue attribute to achieve this. Try the following change in s:radio tag:

```
<s:radio theme="simple" name="cIdDetails"
                    list="cID" onclick="details()" listValue="%{'&nbsp'}"/>
```